# How to change java.util.Logger level on Java EE environment

Tags: jakarta-ee, logging, wildfly

I want to bring to the Java EE application the log configuration. I could be wrong, but my admin is so inacessibly that my user could configure and retrieve the log information more easily than the container admin.

I want to do things like Logger.getLogger(loggerName) and retrieve an Logger not managed by Java EE environment, and do things like logger.setLevel(Level.FINEST), do some work in application, then do logger.setLevel(Level.INFO). On startup I want to do things like starting an logger handler as FileHandler and defining the root logger.

This solution must work on Java EE environments like Websphere 8, Weblogic 11, Wildfly 8.

Can I do this on an Java EE environment and continue using JUL ? How ?

Comment: You definitely don't want to be hacking into the log manager. Have you looked at [logging-profiles](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Logging+Configuration#LoggingConfiguration-LoggingProfiles)?

Comment: Hhhmmm, ok, this could help, but the log files are still in the Java EE admin domain. I'm thinking in adjusting logs Level in runtime(Logger.getLoger(loggerName).setLevel(Level.FINEST)), with the application user effort, so I can change to FINEST for one time then bring back to INFO. I've seen this working in Spring Boot I think, or it was in JHipster, but I don't known if this could work in Java EE environment.

Comment: There are definitely ways to do that, but none of them are really portable. There is no guarantee that an application server will use JUL for the log manager. You will also be affecting logging server wide, not just for the single application.